# How do I create a time-based delay that starts and ends by a clock time?

Tags: debugging, time, service, delay, anylogic

I'm trying to simulate a movie theater. Movies start and end at specified times, no matter when a customer arrives and sits down. I want to be able to start and end the delay by time based units, kicking everyone out at the same time (once the movie is over)

I've tried googling - because I am a student and this was way too ambitious to try but I really wanted to. I'm literally hoping for any kind of insight

Select output, 4 different services (not ped), ped go to, then all same sink

I want it to work and it doesn't

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I am sorry that I do not get your question. Are you doing data-modeling?

Comment: sometimes I leave movies before they end :) Humans are not automats. Some people want to stay and check if there's something after the credits, some people don't. When you model people's behavior, you have to take all these things into consideration... this doesn't answer the question, but I wanted to say that :P

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking of your movie as an agent.  Each movie can have its own event, which you could set to go off at a specific calendar date/time.  In the action of the event, you could send a message to all your customers that they can now leave the theater...or, if your customers are in a queue with a hold block for that particular movie, you can just unblock the hold.

With movies as agents, you could have a start/end time and then create your population of movies from a database linked to Excel.  That is, you would be able to set up your movie schedule outside of AnyLogic, which would probably be easier for whoever your stakeholders are.

Your question is probably too broad to answer fully in stack overflow.  There are a million different ways to model a movie theater, and approach would depend on what you are trying to answer, animation requirements, your comfort level with programming, user interface requirements, etc.